# is there a way to reference a subnet of an IP address dynamically in VCL *varnish) without creating an ACL on a request by request basis?

Tags: varnish

like lets say 72.72.72.72 is the client ip and i wanted to compare it to token or a header that had an IP of 72.72.73.72. basically i want to compare if 72.72.72.72 and 72.72.73.72 but dynamically without an ACL.

so basically if i give out a token as a backend HTTP service and sign it with a secret with certain parameters like an IP address, i want to be able to allow only certain IPs to successfully use that token. like i want to allow all IPs with /20 or so of the IPs in the token i gave out to use that token successfully. Does that make sense @djdomi? i know i can split the token string and get the IP and compare the first 3 octets for an easy /24 comparison but is there an easier way for like /20. you can do this using an ACL but the ACL all the ips must be in there. like is it possible to check client.ip ~ client.ip/20 without using an ACL feature.

Comment: your question is really short. can you please explain the business related problem you are facing and trying to solve? Sometimes is more better ;) Because for it looks for me mixed like a [x and y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)

Comment: so basically if i give out a token as a backend HTTP service and sign it with a secret with certain parameters like an IP address, i want to be able to allow only certain IPs to successfully use that token. like i want to allow all IPs with /20 or so of the IPs in the token i gave out to use that token successfully. Does that make sense @djdomi? i know i can split the token string and get the IP and compare the first 3 octets for an easy /24 comparison but is there an easier way for like /20. you can do this using an ACL but the ACL all the ips must be in there.

Comment: it was meaned that you should edit your question instead writing such important information as a comment ;) and a configuration is also needed due we not wrote that for you but help you to fix it

Comment: ah done thanks @djdomi!

Answer (score 1):

I was super bothered by the fact that we do not have a solution to this problem in [open-source varnish cache](https://varnish-cache.org/) and because it seemed doable in a couple of hours, I wrote [libvmod-acltools](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-acltools) just now.
For now, it only supports converting a single `<ip>/<mask>` into an ACL and I [noticed some limitations in Varnish-Cache](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/3904) which we might want to address.

As Thijs included an ad for Varnish-Software's closed-source product, I would also like to mention that there are some independent open source developers out there like myself and phk:

- see the [CONTRIBUTING section in the README](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-acltools#contributing) on how to support us
- see the [Varnish Moral License](http://phk.freebsd.dk/VML/) on how to support phk

Answer (score 0):

The only way to currently do this is through the `vmod_aclplus`, which is a Varnish Enterprise VMOD. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/aclplus/ for more details.

### The VCL code

Here's some simplified code that gets the subnet from the `token` header.

> In your use case there will probably be some cryptography involved for the token and some `regsub()` magic to extract the subnet from the token.

```
vcl 4.1;

import aclplus;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (aclplus.match(client.ip, req.http.token) {
        return(synth(403));
    }
}
```

Basically the `aclplus.match(IP, STRING)` function allows you to pass an ACL dynamically as a string and match it to an IP address.

Here's an example of potential values that could be stored inside the `token` header:

```
127.0.0.1, !192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.0/16, ::1, !::2, fe00::1/16
```

This mean you can store multiple values in a single line.

### Buying a Varnish Enterprise license

Varnish Enterprise is the commercial version of Varnish and requires a license. See https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/varnish-enterprise/ for information about the license.

### Pay as you use

If you don't want to buy a license upfront and still want to use Varnish Enterprise and `vmod_aclplus`, you can run Varnish Enterprise in the Cloud and get charged on a "pay as you use" basis.

There are official Varnish Enterprise machine images available on the AWS, Azure and GCP marketplaces.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/downloads/#cloud-images for more information.